# How to get this func to work Swift

Tags: swift, swift2

I have 2 funcs

```
func checkEmailField() -> Bool {

    if(!loginPasswordTextField.text!.isEmpty){
        return true
    } else {
        print("Empty Field was found")
       // self.displayMessage(error.localizedDescription, fromViewController: self)
        return false

    }

}
```

and

```
func displayMessage(errorMessage:String?, fromViewController:UIViewController){

    let titleMessage = "Error"
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: titleMessage, message: errorMessage, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let actionOK = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(actionOK)
    fromViewController.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

When i uncomment out that line in the first func() i get an error unresolved identifier error ...how do i pass through error so it works?

Comment: `errorMessage` is just a `String?` you could pass it nil or any String. You are passing it `error.localizedDescription` which is a `String` property on `NSError`, but you never declare `error`, so the compile does not know what `error` is or where it's coming from. Your function is not throwing an `NSError` so there's no error to pass. Seems like you just want to pass `"Empty Field was found"` or something more descriptive for the end user know why they can't proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't have a variable called `error`. You `displayMessage` function expects a string so simply pass it a string:

```
func checkEmailField() -> Bool {
    if(!loginPasswordTextField.text!.isEmpty){
        return true
    } else {
        print("Empty Field was found")
        self.displayMessage("Empty field was found", fromViewController: self)
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: i will mark as correct in 8 minutes when it allows me to